# how to count sequential column and each one is counted before rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, numbers, sequence

I am using `MSSQL` for my application and I need to count sequential number status predecessor line.

Table is like this,

```
+------+------+
|Number|Status|
|     1|     N|
|     2|     G|
|     3|     G|
|     4|     N|
|     5|     N|
|     6|     G|
|     7|     G|
|     8|     N|
+------+------+
```

I suppose result set as follows
    ex.

```
+------+------+-----+
|Number|Status|Count|
|     1|     N| 1   |
|     2|     G| 1   |
|     3|     G| 2   |
|     4|     N| 1   |
|     5|     N| 2   |
|     6|     G| 1   |   
|     7|     G| 2   |   
|     8|     G| 3   |
+------+------+-----+
```

**I couldn't use cursor for performance of query. it is worst case options....**

Comment: what is the logic of count ? ? ? Please provide more detail to understand your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Why does "8" change its value?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify groups of consecutive "N" and "G" values.  I like to approach this with a difference of row numbers.  Then you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows:

```
select t.number, t.status,
       row_number() over (partition by status, grp order by number) as seqnum
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by number) -
              row_number() over (partition by status order by number
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t;
```